# Windows always appear focused

Tags: 11.10

[image]

In the above image i have included an snapshot of the problem. All the windows are behaving like they are focused on oneiric 64 Bit. I tried to change to the default theme. But, no solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Oneiric 64 bit and as you can see (below) focus does have visual effect on window border on default theme but it is subtle. Buttons and title are grayed out and thats about it.

[image]

If you want more visual clues you may want to try compiz plugin Trailfocus from compiz-fusion-plugins-extra package. It makes inactive windows transparent.
You probably need to install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra and compizconfig-settings-manager
Then you go to installed ccsm and turn on checkbox next to trailfocus.